# IntentService Thread.sleep() limit?

Tags: android, multithreading

i was wondering if the `IntentService` has thread blocking limit like calling `Thread.sleep();` and if so what's the maximum time limit for it?

so i wrote the following code snippet:

```
package net.yassin.aaaservice;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private Thread t;
    private static int i = 0;
    private static final int SLEEP_DURATION = 2000;
    private Handler handler;

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        this.handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        this.t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {

                    MyService.this.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MyService.this,
                                    "This is toast #" + (++i),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DURATION);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        this.t.start();
    }
}
```

and i found that whenever i change the time `SLEEP_DURATION` constant to over than 2000 Milis the service will stop showing Toasts if i removed the app form the recent menu?

am i right or there is another time limit or behavior ?
thnx :)

Comment: no,  there is no such limit

Comment: so is there any mistake in this code ?

Comment: cause it stops whenever i remove the app from the recent apps unless if the sleep duration is 2000 or less

Comment: What is actually your goal?  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want the service to log some data every 10 seconds even if the activity is closed.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: thnx @psking very useful :)